# change images with a setinterval and switch statement

Tags: jquery

My idea is change images dynamically through time,but doesn't work .Each box begin with a different image.

```
var dir_img = ['img1.svg','img2.svg','img3.svg'];

        setInterval(function() {
        $('.box img').each(function(){
            var image = $(this).attr('src').val();
            switch(image) {
                case dir_img[0]:
                    $(this).attr('src',dir_img[1]);
                    $(this).hide().delay(0).fadeIn(0).delay(1000).fadeOut(0);
                    break;
                case dir_img[1]:
                     $(this).attr('src',dir_img[2]);
                    $(this).hide().delay(0).fadeIn(0).delay(1000).fadeOut(0);
                    break;
                case dir_img[2]:
                    $(this).attr('src',dir_img[0]);
                    $(this).hide().delay(0).fadeIn(0).delay(1000).fadeOut(0);
                    break;
                default
            }
        });
        }, 1000);
```

A tried get src for 2 ways

```
var image = $(this).attr('src').val();
var image = $(this).attr('src');
```

The boxes and img tags

```
<div class="box">
    <img src="img1.svg">
 </div>
 <div class="box">
    <img src="img2.svg">
 </div>
 <div class="box">
   <img src="img3.svg">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code:

- the `default` state within your `switch` is not closed.
- the variable `este` you are using as a selector is not defined
- `$(this).attr('src');` is the right thing here, the attribute `src` doesn't have a value

With that fixed your code should work.

Note: as you are using the same expression (`$(este).hide().delay(0).fadeIn(0).delay(1000).fadeOut(0);`) in each switch statement you could probably do that outside your switch.

---

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/mjt02x3j/)